# Get two different types of both data and structure from a method

Tags: java, class, methods, jodatime

Below Class is going to compare constant regular daily times and return closest one after now. (using Joda-Time library)

```
public class TimeComparitor {

private List<LocalTime> targetTimes;

public TimeComparitor() {
    targetTimes = new ArrayList<LocalTime>();
}

public void addTargetTime(LocalTime target) {
    targetTimes.add(target);
}

public LocalTime getClosestFutureTarget(DateTime now) {
    LocalTime result = null;
    long resultOffset = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    ArrayList<String> bigger = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (LocalTime target : targetTimes) {
        DateTime todayTarget = target.toDateTimeToday();
        long differenceMillis = todayTarget.getMillis() - now.getMillis();
        if (differenceMillis > 0 && differenceMillis < resultOffset) {
            resultOffset = differenceMillis;
            result = target;
        } 
    }
    return result;
}
```

1.There's `resultOffset` returns variation of the certain time and now, But the method only returns closest time, How to have `resultOffset`'s value out of the class? I've already read some solution for get two values from methods but couldn't adapt it for my code.

2.Also need to have an ordered list of all later times from now, Tried this but wasn't succeed:

```
public LocalTime getClosestFutureTarget(DateTime now) {
    .
    .
    for (LocalTime target : targetTimes) {
                .
                .
                .
        } 
        //My attempt to Get List of Greater Time spots from now
        else if (differenceMillis > 0) {
        private ArrayList<String> sortBigger(LocalTime bigTarget){
                bigger.add(bigTarget.toString());
                Collections.sort(bigger);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: To return two values create an `Object` that holds the two values and return that. In order to order a `List<LocalTime>` you need `LocalTime` to `implements Comparable<LocalTime>`. You could also supply a `Comparator<LocalTime>` to the other `Collections.compare` method.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thanks You Boris.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To return more than one object from a method you can do it via a special class.
Something similar to

```
public class TimeComparisonResult {

    private LocalTime result;
    private long resultOffset;

}
```

And then change getClosestFutureTarget like this.

```
public TimeComparisonResult getClosestFutureTarget(DateTime now) {
```

Then to sort your list you can do it by setting

```
public class LocalTime implements Comparable<LocalTime> {
    ...
    public int compareTo(LocalTime o){
         // compare "this" to o
    }
}
```

For details on how to implement compareTo, you can read this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

and then you can just use `Collections.sort` to sort your list.

Comment: Thank you. You say explicitly but I'm new to both Java and android. I've done something like this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5706952/ but got error on lines 3,4 and 29.
About sorting, is it inside the parent class (`TimeComparitor`) at the end of class?

Comment: @DummyBeginner That is all very wrong. Notice how the code posted by Simon does not have `static` declarations in the utility class. You need to create an instance of the utility class and return that.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yes you're right. I had also used `private` declaration but variables weren't resolved inside `getClosestFutureTarget` method so I changed them to static as IDE had advised. That may seem funny to you but I'm absolutely newbie :D

Comment: A good place to start learning is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ . Escpecially the "Learning the Java Language" section.